# In typescript 0.9.1.1, declare module "jquery" { export = $; } in jquery.d.ts file yields "module expected" in visual studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have been trying to get this to work all day, I have the following typescript(0.9.1.1 release) in one file(a.ts):

```
/// <reference path="declarations/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="declarations/select2/select2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="declarations/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="declarations/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="declarations/blockui/blockui.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="declarations/ObjectSerializer/ObjectSerializer.d.ts" />

    import $ = require('jquery');
// ... code defining a class
```

and I have a declaration/typing file jquery.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

the part that reads:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
```

at the end has an error line that says "module expected" on the export line.

Am I misunderstanding something or what here?

I'm trying to use typescript as AMD compatible(to use requirejs) but this line in the jquery.d.ts line breaks it, with the one error "module expected".

all I should need to generate the necessary

```
require(['require','exports','jquery'], function(require, exports, $) {
//....
});
```

should be the export in jquery.d.ts and the `import $ = require('jquery');` right ?

The end goal is to have a require statement that ensures jquery is loaded before the code in the file executes using requirejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript weirdness....

The problem was encountered and prompted the question on my work computer. After downloading and installing visual studio web express (use pro at work) and typescript dependencies from typescriptlang.org and using nuget to get the jquery.d.ts file the error in the jquery.d.ts file went away (same code though, diff-ed it).

However, Using the express for web version VS at home I found either a weird bug or a bad configuration, here's a description:

From within VS 2012 Express I save the file and when I look at the corresponding js file I see the define statement there but all the imports missing in the actual statement generated. Look below at hello.ts and hello.js and then the hello.js (correctly compiled after rebuilding the solution)

**hello.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
import $ = require('jquery');

import app = require('app');

var a = new app.MyClass('curt');
a.Hello();
```

**hello.js generated by saving the file**

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {




    var a = new app.MyClass('curt');
    a.Hello();
});
//# sourceMappingURL=hello.js.map
```

**hello.js correctly built after rebuilding the solution**

```
define(["require", "exports", 'jquery', 'app'], function(require, exports, __$__, __app__) {
    /// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>
    var $ = __$__;

    var app = __app__;

    var a = new app.MyClass('curt');
    a.Hello();
});
//# sourceMappingURL=hello.js.map
```

Note: saving the file hello.ts always does it wrong, but generates correctly after a rebuild.

If anyone can reproduce this it may need logged as a bug. If not it may be an issue with my build environment. The original issue I had at work(the question) should be resolved if I get typescript uninstalled and reinstalled, as I didn't seem to have that particular issue at home.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import jquery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: Well I tried your suggestion, and there was literally no difference.

I still can't figure out what about this is causing the error because it is the exact same code in as definitelytyped for the jquery.d.ts file.

Still `import $ = require('jquery')`
and `import jquery = require('jquery')` aren't working. However I think there's also something wrong with the declare statement in jquery.d.ts. The version of tsc is 0.9.1.1 and the code I have is exactly what is suggested by others.